# How to get horizontal scrolling in XMonad

Tags: linux, ubuntu-unity, xmonad

I've recently started using XMonad.  While I can use the trackpad to scroll through a web page vertically (top-to-bottom) I cannot use it to scroll horizontally (side-to-side).  How can I set XMonad to recognize that my trackpad supports horizontal scrolling, like it does in e.g. Unity?

I've not seen anything in the searching I've been doing that addresses this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha ha.  That was not an Xmonad problem, it was more generally a Synaptics problem.  Lots of reading led me to [the Ubuntu Synaptics page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad), where I realized there were separate settings for both 2-finger vertical scroll and 2-finger horizontal scroll.  I did the following at the terminal and now things work:

```
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
```